# Footer not flowing to bottom of page

Tags: css

The yellow footer block that appears towards the top of the page should flow to the bottom of the content as a footer normally would.

here is the CSS for #footer:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #2F3B47;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 180px;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

I need the solution to work like a "sticky footer" so that it flows to the bottom of the content block regardless of the heighth of the content div. Thanks for any tips or help!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your wrapper has no associated height, so although the contents fill the div, they aren't *filling out* the div.

One approach you can use is to set a minimum height, this will push the footer down.

```
.wrapper {
min-height:900px;
}
```

However, your problem will persist as your content grows beyond your min-height. One answer is to make sure all your items are held within a DIV. So if you have a .swf that is 500x500, nest it inside a 500x500 div, this way, the contents of your wrapper will ensure that your footer stays at a fixed distance from the bottom of your content

Answer (score 0):

Its not moving to the bottom because you have absolutely positioned all your content. It looks like through scripting youve hacked a height onto `#content` and various other `div`s, but you ave not done so for `#wrapper` therefore `#wrapper` has a computed height of 0 which is used to calculate the position of `#footer` in flow.

There for you need to either rework how youre doing this, ie. use floats instead of positioning, or you need to figure out a way to position the footer properly which could be done by applying the same scripting to `#wrapper` that you have done to various other `div`s, using `position: fixed` as another poster suggested or moving footer inside wrapper and using absolute positioning.

Personally i would rework how youre doing it. ABS positioning has its uses but rarely is layout out an entire page included in these uses :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

In short you have to have a structure that is in two steps (content and footer).

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main" class="clearfix">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

The footer CSS looks :

```
#footer {
position: relative;
margin-top: -150px; 
height: 150px;
clear:both;
}
```

The complete code is very small and is in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the answer of "Felipe Schenone" @ this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Also set Footer "margin-bottom" to 0.

It worked like a charm.